# Make multiple values of a raster layer transparent

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity, band, palette

I have a raster image with a single band with `0` to `255` values styled with a palette of colors. One of the values/colors I want to make transparent is `123`, so I added it in the `Additional no data value` field.

[image: Raster layer properties; transparency]

But I also want to set value `112` as transparent, so I tried adding `123,112` in the `Additional no data value` field, but it appears to not recognize multiple values. How can I make both (or more) values transparent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to input the pixel value in the box below "Custom transparency options". Click on the green plus sign on the right and then add a minimum and a maximum value and set the transparency value. If it's a single value, you can set the minimum and maximum to the same value.